# solr problem:How to make solr repond with only highlighting in xml

Tags: xml, solr, highlighting

I don't want solr to repond with document with all its text because it is too long;
I want solr to repond with only highlighting  in xml.
My English is not well. Hope you would understand me.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you include rows=0, you won't get any document back.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the field that you do not want from `fl` and Solr will not return it.  You can still add that field to highlighting config and Solr will return snippets from the field.  You can also configure Solr to return a small part of the field data if no snippets are generated. (See `hl.maxAlternateFieldLength`)

Comment: note: it's not only about removing redundant fields, but also explicitly including a data field which is not 'score': only then, solr would omit the full-text field

Answer (score 0):

None of these suggestions worked for me, but I did get a solution for SOLR 4.3.  Without the fl parameter in my query, all fields were returned.  Setting fl to the field I am querying (in my case, all content gets shoved into attr_content) still returned the entire document.

The final solution for me was to set the fl query parameter to a non-existent field, like so:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=attr_content:cisco&hl=on&indent=true&hl.fl=*&hl.simple.pre=%3Cem%3E&hl.simple.post=%3C%2Fem%3E&fl=DOES_NOT_EXIST
```